# Scheduled copy of Excel spreadsheet

Tags: powerpivot

### Background

We have a requirement to provide our client updated metrics data on a weekly basis. We wanted to deliver som *wow* so I built out a prototype in Excel using PowerPivot. All is well and good.

We have a manual process (me) to refresh the data and save with a new name (date appended) to a SP library. I'd like to extract myself from the critical path so I'm working with the [PowerPivot Data Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210690.aspx). I have a schedule and it appears my data refresh schedule is working.

### Question

The remaining challenge I have is how can I achieve the publishing/saving as with a different name? Given a template Excel doc, is there a native SharePoint feature/solution for automatically saving it with a new name?

### Etc

I am aware of the ability to have SP track revisions to a document but the terms of our contract call out the need to have different files sitting out there.

Worst case scenario, I can whip up an SSIS package or PowerShell script to copy and rename the file but if I can avoid custom work, I'd prefer it.

Apologies in advance if this is elementary stuff, my google-fu was not strong on this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about OOB feature for that. 
However this can be easy achieve with an event receiver which will intersect when the file is saving and change the name based on you logic.

Read about event receivers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx